# How do players take turn hitting the ball in golf

Tags: rules, golf

Players set off to play in groups everyday. At each hole the partners in a groups tee off and then continue to hit their ball until they make it to the hole.

At each hole, which player tees of first? Once they've all teed, who goes next? Also when can a player hit the ball consecutively without others doing so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the rules:

> 10-1 – Defines the order of play during match play:
>
> - The player who tees off first at the first tee is the first player listed on the scorecard if the scorecard was arranged by authorities; otherwise it is decided by lot or other equitable means. **The player with the lowest score on the previous hole tees off first at the next hole**.
> - **During play of a hole, the player whose ball is farthest from the hole plays next;** if that cannot be determined, any equitable system including by lot (coin flip) or mutual agreement may be used.
> - A player who plays out of turn incurs no penalty, but the opponent who should have played next may require that the stroke be cancelled and replayed at the proper time.

Taken from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rules_of_golf) but that is linked to [USPGA](http://www.usga.org/uploadedFiles/USGAHome/rules/CompleteROGbook.pdf)